# Installing the Clojure language on windows 10

Tags: clojure

Someone knows what software and work environment best to use for the language of `clojure` in `Windows 10` and what should be installed for it.

I tried to install the language in `IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2017.3` by downloading cursive but when I tried to run the following program:

```
(ns clojure.examples.hello
   (: gen-class)

(defn hello-world [username]
   (println (format "Hello,% s" username)))
```

**I encountered the following error:**

> C: \ Users \ user1 \ IdeaProjects \ untitled5> (hello-world "world")
>   'hello-world' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
>   operable program or batch file.

Someone knows what the problem is and can help

thanks!

Comment: I'd install Cursive and follow the user guide there https://cursive-ide.com/userguide

Comment: "Tried to run" it how? A `.clj` file isn't executable, so you can't just invoke it at the command line, any more than you can run an uncompiled file written in C/C++/etc. Regardless, the command you tried to run matters just as much as its output; the question isn't complete without it.

Comment: The code sample has unbalanced parentheses. To me it looks like you need one more right-parentheses after `(: gen class)`. And IIRC there shouldn't be a space between `:` and `gen-class`.

Comment: Thanks a lot it was really effective!!